# Parse error in PHP file when echoing javascript

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

I keep on getting a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in..."

Here's the line thats causing the problem, not sure whats going on here?

```
$text = "<script>window.setInterval(function(){$('#liveData').load('liveUpdate.php');}, 1000);</script>";
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you should re-read how strings work in PHP... The error is obvious :) http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php (hint: you're using a $ inside a string delimited by double quotes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should escape `$` in your `$text`

```
$text = "<script>window.setInterval(function(){\$('#liveData').load('liveUpdate.php');}, 1000);</script>";
```

Or you just use single quote.

Because `$` in double quote will be followed by a php variable name, `$(XXXX` is an invalid PHP variable.

So the best way is to separate javascript (jquery) into a .js file.

Comment: Second the idea of putting this into a separate file, or at least write it as plain javascript - not sure why the assignment to a PHP variable is needed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$text = '<script>window.setInterval(function(){$("#liveData").load("liveUpdate.php");}, 1000);</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '<script>window.setInterval(function(){$("#liveData").load("liveUpdate.php");}, 1000);</script>';
```

Comment: Not for long.. *raises ninja sword...*